# Can I modify a pointer value, from a function, if i receive the pointer address, with a pointer to pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

Here's basically the code:

```
void calculate(int, int, char *, char *, char **); //the prototype of the function
int main(){

  int option;
  int operation_int=0;
  char operation[14];
  char value1[20];
  char value2[20];
  char *result;

  result = (char *)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
  calculate(2, operation_int, value1, value2, &result);

  return 0;
}
void calculate(int option, int operation_integ, char *var1, char *var2, char **res){
  int i=0;
  int value1 = 0;
  int value2 = 0;
  int calc_result = 0;


  switch(operation_integ){

    case 1:

    switch(option){

      case 1:
       break;

      case 2:
      while( ( (var1[i] != '\0') || (var2[i] != '\0') ) ){
        if( (var1[i] != '\0') ){ calc_result= calc_result + ( var1[i] - '0' ) * pow(10,i);}
        if( (var2[i] != '\0') ){ calc_result= calc_result+ ( var2[i] - '0' ) * pow(10,i);}
        i++;
      }

      i=0;

      while(calc_result!= 0){ //HERE IS SOMETHING WRONG
        *(*(res+i)) = (char)calc_result % 10;
        calc_result = calc_result/10;
        i++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So of course, the result of this is "Segmentation Fault".
I think i'm not using properly the pointer to pointer notation, or maybe it's not 'legal' to modify a pointer, from a pointer to pointer, from inside a function. So i'm quite lost with this.

. Can somebody give me some help here?

Comment: Fix your variable names plz, you're declaring them in english and using them in spanish

Comment: Your sample doesn't show where/how resultado is declared or initialized, but it looks like you've given it global scope (could help to understand the sample better to see it). Nevertheless, you seem to be both operating on resultado directly while working with the pointer to you've passed through the call. It's not a very good thing to do because it makes the code hard to follow and any flaw will be hard to spot.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in C.

Answer (score 0):

There's a possible seg fault somewhere else:

```
      while( ( (var1[i] != '\0') || (var2[i] != '\0') ) ){
```

If you'r varN arrays are something like this, for example:

```
var1 = {'2', '1', '\0', '3' .... (other non '\0' chars)};
var2 = {'3', '2', '5', '\0' .... (other non '\0' chars)};
```

Your while loop would continue and eventually may produce a segfault (if you're unlucky, your other variables could be set to 0, ending your while loop but messing your code in such a way that you could hardly notice until you get wrong return values) Especially since you don't seem to be initializing those arrays at all.

Answer (score 0):

One problem:`*(*(res+i))`.

`malloc` returns a pointer to a contiguous block of memory. You're sending `calculate()` the *address* of that pointer as `&result`, then adding `i` to that address. When you dereference this new address with the first (inner) `*`, you get the contents of some random memory for any `i > 0`. If the contents of this random memory don't happen to be a valid memory address, you'll segfault when you try to dereference with the second (outermost) `*`.

I'm guessing you want to increment the pointer returned by `malloc`, in order to access a location in the block of memory it reserved.

You might try declaring your function like this:

```
void calculate(int, int, char *, char *, char *);
```

allocating memory and calling it like this:

```
result = malloc( 20 * sizeof(char) );
calculate(2, operation_int, value1, value2, result);
```

and setting the `i`th char in your `result` block like so:

```
*( res + i*sizeof(char) ) = (char)calc_result % 10
```